# how to increase a search variable by 1 in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

So the task is: Find the youngest sailor in each rating level

-

My tables:

```
Sailors(sid : integer, sname : string, rating : integer, age : real)

Reserves(sid : integer, bid : integer, day : date)

Boats(bid : integer, bname : string, color : string)
```

-

Is something like this even possible:

```
select min(age)

from sailors

where rating =(1++)
```

Comment: what?....have you heard about `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @lamak nope, as you probably understand, i am in the early stages of learning this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select rating,sid,age
 from Sailors as S 
 where (age,rating) 
 in 
 (
     select min(age),rating
      from Sailors
    group by rating
 )
```

**EDIT :**

You could just do `select rating,min(age) from sailors group by rating;` to get the minimum age in the rating level but you won't get the details of the sailor having that minimum age..
Check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55276/1 where you can see that the sid is returned as 5 instead of 8 for rating 4...
where as this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55276/3 returns the sid correctly

Comment: What's the need for the `WHERE ... IN` clause here? You already have the minimum age and rating in the subquery.

Comment: Does MySQL support row and table constructors?

Comment: @Oli In that case i doubt you would get only the min age but not the sailor details

Comment: After testing i bit, i see the advantage in doing it like this. We haven't learned the where-in bit yet, but as far as i can understand its a simple test to see if age and rating is "in" the subquery. Thx anyway.

Comment: And is it not redundant to have this "where 
    rating=S.rating" ?

Comment: @AdF  where-in works the same way as you mentioned....Yeah and "where rating=S.rating"  is redundant ...The advantage of doing the query this way is you also get the details of the sailor else in the accepted answer you get only the minimum age...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT rating, MIN(age)
FROM Sailors
GROUP BY rating;
```

See the MySQL documentation on [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: it would help if you also use `rating` on the `SELECT`

Comment: @Oli I feel a bit embarrased that it was this simple, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select rating,
       min(age)
       from sailors
       where rating in ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 )
       group by rating;
```

But if rating is a table it would be something like

```
select rating.id,
       min(age)
       from sailors inner join rating
       where rating.id = sailors.rating
       group by rating.id;
```

with this as a subquery, you could get the youngest sailor(s) like this:

```
select h.rating,
       sailor.sname,
       sailor.age
from sailor
inner join
     ( select rating,
       min(age) min_age
       from sailors inner join rating
       where rating.id = sailors.rating
       group by rating.id;
     ) h
where h.rating = sailor.rating
and   h.min_age = sailor.age;
```

Comment: heh, would this work if two sailors had the same rating and age ?

Comment: Yes it would. Not sure if your data contains multiple minimum ages per rating, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT MIN(age), rating
FROM   Sailors
GROUP BY rating
```

Comment: cheers, my first encounter with this community was better than i expected ;)